# Create a temporary container and append all body content to that container

Tags: javascript, fragment, appendchild

What I am attempting to do with **JavaScript** (no libraries) is to create a fragment append all the content of the body into that fragment:

```
var _fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    _children = document.body.childNodes;

for( var i=0,_clen=_children.length; i<_clen; i++ ) {
    _fragment.appendChild( _children[i] );
}
```

This does not seem to be working for some reason.

Best,
Speedy

------------- Edit --------------

I added a check to see if the node was not undefined and it worked.

```
for( var i=0,_clen=_children.length; i<_clen; i++ ) {
    if( _children[i] !== undefined ) {
        _fragment.appendChild( _children[i] );
    }
}
```

Thanks for the responses folks!

Speedy

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: I am getting a NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var bodyContent = body.innerHTML;
var newElement = document.createElement("DIV");
newElement.innerHTML = bodyContent;

// adding the new element to the body
body.appendChild(newElement);
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/Dh3Q3/